# Behavior of std::complex on undefined results

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

On [page 1052](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4659.pdf#page=1052) of (the openly accessible draft of) the C++17 standard, it says that calling a function which has a mathematically undefined result is undefined behavior. For example,

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <complex>

int main() {
    std::cout << std::complex<double>(0., 0.) / std::complex<double>(0., 0.);
    return 0;
}
```

prints `(-nan,-nan)` on clang 7.

Float division by zero is undefined behavior in general, but implementations may follow IEEE-754 semantics (Annex F in the C standard, and mentioned in passing in some of the C++ standard, but I'm not sure on that point). So float division by zero is defined to be NaN in implementations in which `std::numeric_limits<double>::is_iec559` is true.

This is a language lawyer question, so I'm not sure why the comments are going down the path of "undefined behavior can do anything". Of course, but is it a defect in the standard that the results are not specified (or considered implementation-defined) for implementations that follow IEEE-754?

Comment: What do you mean by "optimize on that basis"? Undefined behavior essentially gives the compilers freedom on how to handle that, but most likely it will be implemented with minimum performance impact

Comment: [Undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) and [Undefined behavior can result in time travel (among other things, but time travel is the funkiest)](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140627-00/?p=633)

Comment: I know undefined behavior gives the compiler license to do anything. The question  is whether it's sensible, then, to explicltly handle these cases, or just assume they return a nan result.

Comment: Sorry but, am I missing something? There is no point in this discussion as the programmer must always take conditions into account. By writing a program you are creating logic including the simplest example; hello world. It sounds pretty unreasonable/illogical to ask how many times 0 contains 0.

Comment: The only sensible way is to avoid the undefined behavior from happening. By definition you are not guaranteed with any contract of what should happen, so the inconsistencies between compilers are very likely, let alone the same behavior may change in future for the same compiler of different version.

Comment: Most compilers implement IEEE-754 standard for floating point numbers, so it may be defined for that compiler, that architecture, etc. If `std::numeric_limits<double>::is_iec559()` returns `true`, you can be fairly certain these particular dragons are rather tame.

Comment: To rephrase: "Does `is_iec559() == true` require that division by complex zero produces `nan, nan`? I think the answer is "no" because IEC559 does not cover complex arithmetic.

Comment: @RaymondChen Thanks for actually answering my question!